# Sencha Touch 2 Search List

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

am having issue designing and getting a search field to work, i don't know how to get this working, i can see any documentation or sample code on Sencha Touch 2. any help will be appreciated. this my current stage:

```
`Ext.define('ikhlas.view.SearchProfile', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'searchpanel',

    config:{
            title: 'Search',
                iconCls: 'search',
                scrollable: true,
                styleHtmlContent: true,

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
                title:'Search Profile',
                iconCls:'add',

    items: [

            {

            xtype: 'searchfield',
                name:'searchfield',
                placeHolder:'Search',
            },

           ]    

        },

           ]

        }

});`
```

And my controller looks like this (Noting has been done, i don't know how to start help pls):

```
Ext.define('ikhlas.controller.SearchField',{
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config:{
    refs:{
        submitpanel:'loginpanel'
    },

control:{

    }
},

  });
```

And here are the list of Data's i want to Auto search:

```
data: [
            {firstName: 'Tommy',   lastName: 'Maintz'},
            {firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Dougan'},
            {firstName: 'Ed',      lastName: 'Spencer'},
            {firstName: 'Jamie',   lastName: 'Avins'},
            {firstName: 'Aaron',   lastName: 'Conran'},
            {firstName: 'Dave',    lastName: 'Kaneda'},
            {firstName: 'Michael', lastName: 'Mullany'}
```

i want the search field to work in such a way that as the user is typing in character, it will auto pop suggestion just like: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/search-list

Comment: Since you are using their same example, you can check their own documentation code for this example (shipped with their sdk) ..

Answer (score 3):

In your controller you should listen for two events, clearicontap and keyup for the searchfield.

```
...
control: {
    'searchfield': {
        keyup: 'onSearchQueryChanged',
        clearicontap: 'onSearchReset'
    }
},

onSearchQueryChanged: function(field) {
    // as in sample
    //get the store and the value of the field
        var value = field.getValue(),
            store = this.getStore(); //you should actually point to the real store

        //first clear any current filters on thes tore
        store.clearFilter();

        //check if a value is set first, as if it isnt we dont have to do anything
        if (value) {
            //the user could have entered spaces, so we must split them so we can loop through them all
            var searches = value.split(' '),
                regexps = [],
                i;

            //loop them all
            for (i = 0; i < searches.length; i++) {
                //if it is nothing, continue
                if (!searches[i]) continue;

                //if found, create a new regular expression which is case insenstive
                regexps.push(new RegExp(searches[i], 'i'));
            }

            //now filter the store by passing a method
            //the passed method will be called for each record in the store
            store.filter(function(record) {
                var matched = [];

                //loop through each of the regular expressions
                for (i = 0; i < regexps.length; i++) {
                    var search = regexps[i],
                        didMatch = record.get('firstName').match(search) || record.get('lastName').match(search);

                    //if it matched the first or last name, push it into the matches array
                    matched.push(didMatch);
                }

                //if nothing was found, return false (dont so in the store)
                if (regexps.length > 1 && matched.indexOf(false) != -1) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    //else true true (show in the store)
                    return matched[0];
                }
            });
        }
},

onSearchReset: function(field) {
    this.getStore().clearFilter();
}

...
```

This example will emulate the same behavior as in ST2 SDK, that is filtering a store of `Ext.List`. Naturally, you will probably end up implementing your own logic for filtering.

Note that `searchfield` is nothing more but a styled `textfield`, usually with clear button to the right (depends on browser/os), as defined in HTML5.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Grgur, How can i set up my store so as to retrieve this values when i try searching for them? thanks. ` {firstName: 'Tommy',   lastName: 'Maintz'},
            {firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Dougan'},
            {firstName: 'Ed',      lastName: 'Spencer'},
            {firstName: 'Jamie',   lastName: 'Avins'},
            {firstName: 'Aaron',   lastName: 'Conran'},
            {firstName: 'Dave',    lastName: 'Kaneda'},
            {firstName: 'Michael', lastName: 'Mullany'}`

Comment: If you're filtering on server, then you just need to send the right filter. Otherwise, wait for store to load, use 'load' event for it and when done send the filtering callback so that filtering happens when data is ready

Comment: Hi Grgur, i managed to achieve somthing like this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596404/need-help-in-sencah-touch-2-search-list refer to the line and help me from there. thanks.