# Need Help In Sencah Touch 2 Search List

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i have problem achieving the exact result i want in building a sencha Search List, i managed to build just a list but the actual result i want is just something like this http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/search-list i have followed the example to build something similar, but my serach is not working, hope somebody can give me a detailed answer on how to achive this. below are my codes from my controller to the last.

this is my controller
    Ext.define('List.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

```
config: {
    refs: {
        main: 'mainpanel'
    },
    control: {
        'presidentlist': {
            disclose: 'showDetail'
        }
    }
},

showDetail: function(list, record) {
    this.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'presidentdetail',
        title: record.fullName(),
        data: record.getData()
    })
}
```

});
 This is my model

```
Ext.define('List.model.President', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: ['firstName', 'middleInitial', 'lastName']
},

fullName: function() {
    var d = this.data,
    names = [
        d.firstName,
        (!d.middleInitial ? "" : d.middleInitial + "."),
        d.lastName
    ];
    return names.join(" ");
}
```

});

this is my store

```
Ext.define('List.store.Presidents', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

config: {
    model: 'List.model.President',
    sorters: 'lastName',
    grouper : function(record) {
        return record.get('lastName')[0];
    },
    data: [
        { firstName: "George", lastName: "Washington" },
        { firstName: "John", lastName: "Adams" },
        { firstName: "Thomas", lastName: "Jefferson" },
        { firstName: "James", lastName: "Madison" },


    ]
}
```

});
 this is my views, under my view folder,

```
Ext.define('List.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
xtype: 'mainpanel',
requires: [
    'List.view.PresidentList',
    'List.view.PresidentDetail'
],

config: {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'presidentlist'
    }]
}
```

});

still under my view folder PresidentDetail

```
Ext.define('List.view.PresidentDetail', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'presidentdetail',

config: {
    title: 'Details',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    tpl: [
        'Why Not Work {firstName}  {lastName}!'
    ]
}
```

});

still under my view folder i have another file called PresidentList

```
Ext.define('List.view.PresidentList', {
extend: 'Ext.List',
xtype: 'presidentlist',
requires: ['List.store.Presidents'],

config: {
     xtype:'container',
    title: 'Why Not Work',
    grouped: true,
    itemTpl: '{firstName} {lastName}',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    store: 'Presidents',
    onItemDisclosure: true,

     items: [

            {

            xtype: 'searchfield',
                name:'searchfield',
                placeHolder:'Search',
            },

         {

            xtype: 'spacer',
               height: 25
            },
           ] 
}
```

});

This is my App.js file

Ext.application({
    name: 'List',

```
requires: [
    'Ext.field.Search'
],

controllers: ['Main'],
views:  ['Main'],
stores: ['Presidents'],
models: ['President'],

launch: function() {
    Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'mainpanel'
    });
}
```

});

Am sorry i have to post my whole app here, am just trying to get my qestion as detailed as possible. at the moment, my current app displays as this but the search field is not functioning. i need help please thanks

[image: my current output]

i seriously need help please. the result i wish to achieve is something like this so that once the user is about to search the field, the list of the names stored starting from R will all show up:
[image: This is what i need]

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Here's is the code for the search list demonstrated in the Sencha Touch documentation http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/examples/list-search/ Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to listen for modifications on search field and filter the store based on the value.

This is the kind of modification you need to make to your controller:

```
config: {
    refs: {
        main: 'mainpanel'
    },
    control: {
        'presidentlist': {
            disclose: 'showDetail'
        },

        'searchfield': {
            keyup: 'doSearch'
        }
    }
},

showDetail: function(list, record) {
    this.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'presidentdetail',
        title: record.fullName(),
        data: record.getData()
    })
},

doSearch: function(field) {
    var value   = field.getValue(),
        store   = this.getPresidentList().getStore(),
        query   = new RegExp(value, 'i');

    store.filter('firstName', query)
}
```

Also, I would add another field to the model that combines first and last name (e.g. fullName) and search against it.

Comment: Hi Grgur, am still waiting for you field to add up to my model which will combine the first and last name. help me out pls thanks

Comment: in Model: 

fields: ['firstName', 'middleInitial', 'lastName', {
 name: 'fullName',
 mapping: 'firstName',
 convert: function (value, rec) {
  return value + ' ' + rec.get('lastName');
 }
}]